# How to prove the autocorrelation of this random variable is just related to time difference?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, correlation

Assume $X_n$ is an iid gaussian random process with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$, and $U_n$ be an iid binary random process with $P_r\{ U_{n}=1\}=P_r\{U_n=-1\}=0.5$, and $\{U_n\}$ is independent of $\{X_n\}$, now let $Z_n=X_n U_n$.

Now,i want to prove the $Z_n$ is WSS, and we know if some random process is WSS, it should satisfy these two properties

$1$. Mean is a constant value

$2$. Autocorrelation is just related to time difference

And i know the mean of $Z$ is zero, and zero is a constant, but how do i prove the second property?

Comment: The question has given $X_n, U_n$ are i.i.d. So is $Z_n$ also i.i.d.? If yes, then what is its auto-correlation?

Comment: @BGM I think the $Z_n$ is also iid,too.i have some think from your reply.According to the def of auto-correlation,$E[Z(t)Z(t+\tau)]$,and the def of iid,the $E[Z(t)Z(t+\tau)]$ can be separated to $E[Z(t)]E[Z(t+\tau)]=0$,and it is not the related to time difference,so it is not WSS.Do you mean this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see that $Z_n$ has the same distribution as $X_n$, but I leave the argumentation to you (does an equiprobable sign flip change a symmetric PDF?). The autocorrelation of $Z_n$ is thus the same as that of $X_n$, i.e.
\begin{align*}
R_{ZZ}(m,n) &= R_{XX}(m,n) = \mathrm{E}[X_m X_n]
= \sigma^2 \delta_{m,n} \\
&= 
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\sigma^2 & \text{if } m = n \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right. \\
&=
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\sigma^2 & \text{if } m-n = 0 \\
0 & \text{if } m-n \neq 0
\end{array}\right. \\
&= \tilde{R}_{ZZ}(m-n)
\end{align*}
which is a function of $m-n$.

Comment: I agree with yours thinking for first sentence,but can't prove it. what is the $Z_n$ pdf ?because the $X_n$ is a continuous pdf,but the $U_n$ is the discrete time pmf.why is  the  $Z_n$  has the same distribution as $X_n$ when  $X_n$ multiply $U_n$??

Comment: @ShineSun Using marginalization of the joint PDF of $Z_n$ and $U_n$ (and short-hand PDF notation) $f(Z_n) = \sum_u f(Z_n,U_n=u) =  \sum_u f(Z_n|U_n=u) \cdot \mathrm{Pr}(U_n=u) =  f(Z_n | U_n = 1) \cdot \mathrm{Pr}(U_n = 1) + f(Z_n | U_n = -1) \cdot \mathrm{Pr}(U_n = -1) = f(X_n) \frac{1}{2} + f(-X_n) \frac{1}{2} = f(X_n) \frac{1}{2} + f(X_n) \frac{1}{2} = f(X_n)$